# Автоматизация конвертации word to pdf и защита pdf

Tags: pdf, ms-word

Есть ли такой софт?

Конвертирую онлайн, а защищаю PDFill PDF Tools.
Файлов порядка 500, они в папках, есть и вложенные папки.

P.S. Уже конвертировал:

```
Наличие LibreOffice
example: lowriter --convert-to pdf *.doc or *.docx or *.rtf
```

Теперь нужно защитить от копирования и т.д.  
Под винду есть софт, но он платный, и можно выбрать только 1 файл.

upd: был написан софт который запускает один шифратор у которого есть консольный интерфейс, но т.к. он платный, то он ставит watemark

Comment: Защита файла от копирования - это один файл в заголовке, который запрещает просмотрщику копировать. Линуксовые просмотрищики смотрят на этот флаг как на что то лишнее и просто игнорируют. Платить за подобное не вижу смысла.

Answer (score 2):

Могу сделать нечитаемый PDF и для него вьювер , ессесно который только один сможет открывать такие документы.

Ну или можно предложить оригинальный шифрованный упаковщик-распаковщик PDF контента. Гарантированно, никто не прочитает кроме вас.

Ну а если бесплатно, то можно использовать стандартные методы Adobe - подписи контента, шифрование и секьюрити флаги.